# Should I write automated unit tests that fail when the code changes?

Tags: unit-testing, test-coverage

Generally when writing automated unit tests (eg JUnit, Karma)  I aim to:

- cover all the boundary conditions
- get a high level of coverage.

I heard someone say:

> coverage and boundary conditions aren't enough for a unit test, you need to write them so they will break if the code changes.

This sounds good to me in theory - but I'm not sure how to apply it.

My question is: **Should I write automated unit tests that fail when the code changes? If so, how.**

Comment: where did you hear that and how exactly it was stated? (FWIW as quoted it doesn't make sense - you likely misunderstood)

Comment: Automated tests aren't meant to break when code changes. They're meant to ensure that when you change code that your code still works to spec, and if it doesn't THEN fail.

Comment: There is a reason for a code to fail. That is when a procedure or business logic changes. Unit tests cannot predict domain changes, so if you do that, then the tests should fail and they should be rewritten. If you, however, only refactor code to make it faster, better (, stronger?), then all your unit tests should work even after you are done with the changes.

Comment: I can see writing unit tests that run if and only if code changes.  Even a basic Makefile can do that.  But the unit test should only "fail" if the changed code actually fails the unit test.  You can always have the unit tests emit a message to say when it actually runs.

Comment: Wait, why is this tagged [tag:java] [tag:javascript] [tag:junit]?

Comment: Next time, when someone tells you have wrong assumptions in your questions, edit it by yourself to remove that assumptions.

Comment: @DocBrown after editing the question, it is often helpful to re-check if changes invalidated some answers and warn answerers if this is the case (as far as I can tell, question edit in rev 3 impacted 4 prior answers)

Comment: Thanks - that's really helpful. I've updated the question. Hopefully it makes more sense.

Comment: Your colleague isn't saying that you should write tests that fail if the code is changed at all; they're saying that there is no possible change to the code that would cause the test to fail, and the test therefore does not actually test the code.

Comment: That edit _completely_ changes the meaning of the question, by the way. I see three answers, and they've _all_ been invalidated.

Comment: @BlacklightShining:  There are actually six answers; three, including mine, have been deleted.  This question should have been allowed to die with dignity instead of edited.

Comment: @gnat: wrong adress, I am well aware of what you wrote. My original edit did not change the question and its meaning that much, all the existing answer were still valid at that time. The OP was the one himself changed the quote so much that it invalidated the answers.

Comment: @BlacklightShining Has mine been invalidated? Do you think it could be corrected with an edit?

Comment: @Blrfl But they were very good answers! They were just answers to _another question._ Without knowing how this situation is normally handled, my instinct is that the question should be rolled back to a point before the answers were invalidated, and a new one should be asked.

Comment: @BenAaronson Basically, yeah! The answer has gone from _make your tests break when the behavior changes, not when the code does_ to _you've misunderstood your colleague_. While an answer in the former style would still be _kind of_ relevant, it would work better as a side note than the focus of the answer.

Comment: @BlacklightShining Rolling back to DocBrown's revision might be a good solution. But I'm not exactly seeing your point. The actual question is the part in bold, the rest is preamble to justify why the questioner is asking this in the first place. It seems like the existing answers are still relevant as answers to that bolded question. Then wouldn't all they (possibly need) be a "and this is probably what your co-worker was trying to say"?

Comment: @BlacklightShining Well, to be a bit clearer, not really "this is what your co-worker was trying to say" so much as "and what your co-worker was saying is compatible with this"

Comment: @BlacklightShining:  Unfortunately, that train has sailed.  I'll undelete my answer if the question is reverted.

Comment: @hawkeye: you probably misunderstood my suggestion. I already removed the wrong assumptions from your question, but afterwards you changed the quote which modified the meaning so much that it invalidated some of the existing, highly voted answers. Please consider to revert the edits back to rev. 3 (I could do this on my own, but IMHO that would actually be too rude).

Comment: Thanks @DocBrown I've reverted the changes for the sake of the Programmers SA community. (I've got the answer to my actual question).

Comment: @DocBrown I think it was your edit in [Rev 3](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/posts/306963/revisions) that killed the answers, you can find them by my comments pointing that statement they heavily rely upon was deleted. Not that I complain, answerers did shoots in the dark and missed. Per se, changes you made were really good, they turned very vague question into a clear and useful one. OP somewhat obscured it in Rev 4 but fortunately they recovered it in Rev 5

Comment: @gnat: thanks for your remark, and maybe my edit killed some of the more uninteresting answers, which took the wrong assumption of the OP for granted. But for my defense: I actually left the question "how to write unit tests that fail when code changes" as a secondary question in the text, I just **added** the question "should I do this" as a primary one to the whole thing. I did not change the original quote, in no way, but the OP did in Rev 4. That invalidated Joppe's answer, which is IMHO worth to be rescued.

Comment: @DocBrown I see no easy way to resque answer you worry about. Per my reading, if the invalidated part was stripped out of it, it would turn into a brief remark merely repeating what is stated (and I think much better explained) in the top answer

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Your aim should be not to write unit tests that fail when the *code* changes, but unit tests that fail when the **behaviour** changes. Here, behaviour means anything that an external caller of the method wants it to do, like returning the right response to a question or saving the right thing to a databse. *How* it achieves that is its own internal implementation, not its behaviour.

By testing behaviour rather than implementation, you can refactor code to make improvements, and instantly verify whether you've accidentally changed the way it behaves by running your tests.

In reality, it's not possible to perfectly achieve this goal. If you have a method:

```
int add(int x, int y) {
    return x + y;
}
```

You can write as many unit tests as you want for it, but it's extremely unlikely any of them will fail if you modify it to:

```
int add(int x, int y) {
    if(x==10731 && y == -405571) {
        return 0;
    }
    return x + y;
}
```

However, you can take some sensible steps to get as close to full behavioural coverage as is practical:

- As you said, think about boundary conditions and corner cases. These are the places where you're most likely to see accidental behaviour change.
- Think of line-by-line coverage as "necessary, but not sufficient". Imagine trying to be as lazy as you possibly can while still getting full line-by-line coverage, and you'll see how easy it is to write an inadequate set of tests that follow this
- Think about the behaviour your method is supposed to provide, and the branches it can follow. Ideally you should test that for every route through its implementation, it provides all the behaviour that's expected.
- When you've written a set of tests, ask "Are there any implementations of my method which are at least as simple as the existing one, which would pass all of my tests, but which have the wrong behaviour?" This is a good rule of thumb to see if your behavioural coverage is good enough.

  As shown in the example `add` method above, you can never really fully defend against modifications to your method that add extra stuff to it, making it less simple. But much more likely, bugs are going to sneak in through modifying or removing parts, without adding to the complexity (because, why would you refactor something in a way that adds to its complexity?). So by adding the "at least as simple" condition, you get something practically achievable.

Comment: I will note that your example bug *would* be caught if you ensure 100% branch coverage when running your tests.  Such tests might not need to be written by hand.  Even an automated tool like (C#) Pex (e.g., paste [this code](http://pastebin.com/0LvXV0tX) into [Pex4Fun](http://pex4fun.com/default.aspx?language=CSharp&sample=_Template)) would catch this type of bug, though I'm unsure what sort of tools exist for Java.

Comment: @Brian Agreed. There's also things like property-based tests that can make special cases at least *more* likely to be caught. Nothing's foolproof though, and I didn't want to muddy the answer with increasingly advanced ways to plug an increasingly small hole

Comment: This is a really helpful constructive answer. I've updated the quote - would you consider updating your question?

Comment: @Brian: And let's not forget branch-aware fuzzing, AFL or the LLVM's libFuzzer are examples of libraries that observe the code behavior at run-time and try to generate input that triggers new code paths.

Comment: Fuzzing is interesting - I'm told the tool that specifically addresses this problem is a mutation test tool: http://mutation-testing.org/

Comment: @Brian: If the type is 64 bit integer, you will _not_ have complete coverage.

Comment: @hawkeye I'm not sure what you mean by "updating my question". I've already voted to reopen and I hope you hit the threshold, because in its current state the question should be open.

Answer (score 0):

The answers given - that this is a wrongheaded thing to do, and violates every principle of good testing - are correct.

But this is programming. There are always *some* sensible rationales for even the strangest request, and it can be productive to consider them.

Say you have some critical kernel code, or some high-security part of your SSH library, which absolutely, under no circumstances, should ever change its behavior, not even for some tiny subset of the infinite values it takes, all of which you could never test against.

And say you have a company set up such that there is a QA department responsible for writing unit tests against code provided by the Dev deparment, to ensure it meets business requirements.

In this situation, it makes sense to say "the critical code paths should only be modified by Dev *when QA has been notified with signoff by upper management*." Any change without signoff and notification is non-deliberate, and may be malicious.

In that case, a test which uses introspection to get a hash of the contents of each method, and compare that to a stored hash, could be legitimate. You can't serialize Method(), but you could subclass Method to be serializable. Perhaps a better approach is to get a hash of the file itself. Or just compare the file to a secure backup of the file.

But probably the best approach if the requirement is to fail on any modification, is to check the versioning system's logs and see if any changes were downloaded for the relevant files. If yes, then fail.

Comment: "QA department responsible for writing unit tests" Please, no.

Comment: @Celos - Coders should write low-level unit tests as they code. But another layer of higher level tests written by people who *are not the people writing the code* exposes a plethora of spec issues that you simply can't ever through coder testing. All too many places leave spec-compliance-testing to some combo of [arbitrary coder decision;  manual QA tests; wishful thinking]. Like art and UI design, automated testing's a separate concern and specialization from coding, and most coders who think that they can do these things just fine, simply haven't a clue.

Comment: In the case where sign-off to the code is required, you shouldn't use _tests_ for that. There are better tools for that job, ones that operate on an entirely different level from unit tests.